# How to use ENV Variables Declared on Google Cloud Run Dashboard in React

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

I am deploying a create-react-app Service onto Google Cloud Run using a Dockerfile, but I want to move away from declaring env variables in a .env file, and instead, declare them on Google Cloud Run's Dashboard like so:

[image: Dashboard Image]

However, when I call the env var using

```
console.log("REDIRECT", process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI)
```

null is returned for any env variable I try to reference. Is there another step to access these variables that I am missing?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template
ENV PORT 8080 
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT'  < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template >      /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: are you hosting you app as node process or static hosting ?

Comment: I believe as a node process?

Comment: can you add your docker file ?

Comment: Just added the Dockerfile.

Comment: Do you have anything in your `process.env` ? Also in your picture you don't set any value, it's to hide value right?

Comment: I have absolutely the same issue. Did you manage to handle it?

Comment: I sort of gave up with this approach and instead just use a local .env file, which I populate using a shell script that manages my deployment process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your container serve only static files (through NGINX) and no processing is performed on Cloud Run side.

Actually, you expose your static file to your users. The users get the files and load them in their browser. The users' browser execute the Javascript and read the Env Variable on the current environment: the users' browser.

Therefore, the Cloud Run env var aren't use in this use case. You have to perform a processing on Cloud Run to use the Cloud Run env variables.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you mean by "local processing on Cloud Run", or maybe point me to some resources about this. Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: Ok, I removed the "local". In fact, the env var are only for Cloud Run process. You should have an execution that run on Cloud Run to use the env vars. If you code is ran on the user side (in the browser) the env vars aren't populated