# REACT APP not access the google cloud run environment variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, google-cloud-run

I am using GitLab ci as my CI/CD tool. I am deploying the dockerized react app to cloud run but I am not able to access the environment variables declared on cloud run. Thank you!

**Dockerfile**

```
# build environment
FROM node:8-alpine as react-build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# server environment
FROM nginx: alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template

COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080
CMD sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
default:
  image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
  before_script:
    - gcloud config set project PROJECTID
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GCP_SERVICE_CREDS
stages:
  - staging
  - production

staging:
  stage: staging
  environment:
    name: staging
  only:
    variables:
      - $DEPLOY_ENV == "staging"
  script:
    - gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECTID/REPOSITORY
    - gcloud run deploy REPOSITORY --image gcr.io/PROJECTID/REPOSITORY --platform managed --region us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated 

production:
  stage: production
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    variables:
      - $DEPLOY_ENV == "production"
  script:
    - gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECTID/REPOSITORY
    - gcloud run deploy REPOSITORY --image gcr.io/PROJECTID/REPOSITORY --platform managed --region us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --set-env-vars NODE_ENV=production
```

Comment: Which environment are you trying to access the variable? There's no env variable configured on your "staging" app.

Comment: On both staging and production my environment variables are declared on cloud run service

Answer (score 2):

Credits to Guillaume Blaquiere because this answer is based on his post from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64023758/7031308).

According to React [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/):

> **The environment variables are embedded during the build time**. Since Create React App produces a static HTML/CSS/JS bundle, it can’t possibly read them at runtime. To read them at runtime, you would need to load HTML into memory on the server and replace placeholders in runtime.

Most likely what happens is that you expose static files to your users and the users get the files and load them in their browser like this:

```
console.log("REDIRECT", process.env.REACT_APP_API_END_POINT)
```

This returns `null` because the users' browser execute the Javascript and read the env variable on the current environment: the users' browser. You should have an execution that run on Cloud Run to use the env vars. If the code is ran on user side (in their browser), the env vars will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to access environment variables declared on GCP such as $GCP_SERVICE_CREDS, $PROJECTID, $REPOSITORY and others on your Gitlab pipeline.

To do this, go to Gitlab settings then click on CI/CD. Once there, click on the Expand button in front of Variables and you add your various GCP variables with their Values.

Comment: S, these variable $GCP_SERVICE_CREDS, $PROJECTID, $REPOSITORY are on GitLab the are being accessed successfully but the ENVs on google cloud run like REACT_APP_API_END_POINT is undefined.

Comment: You must define the variable during deployment with the `gcloud run deploy` command using `--set-env-vars REACT_APP_API_END_POINT =`

Comment: @UsamaKhan The proper syntax is `--set-env-vars "KEY1=VALUE1"`, there should be no spaces in between the key and the value. Please double check and update your post so we can see how you configure it on your `gcloud run deploy`.

Comment: These environment  variable are hard coded in cloud run service in "edit and deploy new revision" there is an option to set environment variable. I have one cloud run service for my node backend and one service is for react front end but incase of node it picked the environment variable but for react it didn't pick that.