# Properly defining environment variables in Cloud Run for my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app, google-cloud-run

I am currently deploying a react application (front-end only) using Cloud Run, I have created a trigger for a cloud build to run which deploys the app using Cloud Run.

However, when I'm trying to create some environment variables to access in my components using cloud run UI I cannot access them due to the fact (from my understanding) that the environments are defined within the instance of the app and not the user's browser.

So my question is - How should I properly approach this issue?
I've tried perhaps building sort of "config.json", but I wasn't able to find a proper way to mount the files in different environments.

Comment: are you using `create react app`?

Comment: Yes, i'm using CRA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ENV Variables Declared on Google Cloud Run Dashboard in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016442/how-to-use-env-variables-declared-on-google-cloud-run-dashboard-in-react)

Comment: @LluísMuñoz This describes my problem yes, however I did not manage to find a solution there.
I didn't understand what processing on cloud run mean?

Comment: As I understand it the environment variables declared in the Cloud Run console are used when running a process in Cloud Run deployment. Since your application is front-end only you are not executing any processes in Cloud Run, besides serving the static files. Therefore the processing is being done in the users’ browser, which is where your React app is looking for environment variables, not your Cloud Run deployment.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do the following. First, install https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd

Next, you can specify the .env to be used depending upon your environment as so. The below code allows you to specify configuration declaratively rather than imperatively. Now, when you say `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV1` `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV2` `process.env.REACT_APP_ENV3`, then depending on env the correct values will be transparently picked up.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f env_anotherenv.env react-scripts start",
    "start_vscode": "env-cmd -f env_vscode.env react-scripts start",
    "build_staging": "env-cmd -f env_staging.env react-scripts build --profile",
    "build_production": "env-cmd -f env_production.env react-scripts build --profile"
}
```

Example of env_production.env will be

```
REACT_APP_ENV1 = someenv1
REACT_APP_ENV2 = someenv2
REACT_APP_ENV3 = someenv3
```

Example of env_staging.env will be

```
REACT_APP_ENV1 = someotherenv1
REACT_APP_ENV2 = someotherenv2
REACT_APP_ENV3 = someotherenv3
```

Comment: I want to avoid pushing .env files to the repository, how will this work when I deploy my app using cloud build + run?

Comment: This would expose our env variables in the repository

Comment: @kishorekumaru you can't to anything about that, it is a react app and runs in the browser and as such env variable that the react app running in the browser needs will always be exposed. 

If you want to hide env variables then run it on the server

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you bake in your environment variables in your build artifacts which you then access using `process.env.VARIABLE_1` as described [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

Use a multi-stage docker build. In your build stage populate a .env file from build-args (e.g using envsubst) before running `npm run build`. Here is a sample using a template that you can push to your git repo.

```
ARG VARIABLE_1
ARG VARIABLE_2
COPY .env.template .
RUN /bin/sh -c "envsubst '\$VARIABLE_1 \$VARIABLE_2' < .env.template > .env"
```

.env.template

```
VARIABLE_1=${VARIABLE_1}
VARIABLE_2=${VARIABLE_2}
```

Depending on how your cloud build triggers are [set up](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger), the values for the build args can be sourced from substitution variables.
The final stage can be based on the nginx image, here you copy the built static files bundle and serve using nginx. See a full docker example [here](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/)

This way you do not expose a .env file and there is no environment variables configuration to be done from the cloud run end.